# Statistical analysis for PHP

Tags: php, statistics

I am trying to write a reporting system for a project I'm working on that analyzes people's pre and post test scores and does some analysis on it.  I have searched to the best of my ability, but cannot find a PHP Class / set of functions that seems to do the analysis I need.

Currently, I am dumping the dataset to a CSV, and one of my co-workers is running it through SPSS to perform a paired-samples t-test (that's the analysis I need run, as we need the p-value).

I know that there is this class in PHP: http://usphp.com/manual/en/ref.stats.php,
however, none of that seems to be documented to the point that I can understand it.

I don't mind having to write the analysis myself, but if it already exists, I would like to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what sort of reporting are you wanting to produce? Charts?

Comment: I already produce all the charts and average's I need.  I literally JUST need to calculate the statistical p value for my data sets.

Comment: You could use the power of R to do statistics for you and call it directly from php. http://www.matthewjockers.net/2008/11/11/executing-r-in-php/

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're going to want to use the **stats_stat_paired_t** function. I'm not sure if you've tried this yet, but you may be able to figure out if this function does what you need it to do by looking at its [source code](http://pecl.php.net/package/stats). Look in statistics.c, line 3201.

Comment: From what I can tell, that generated the t-value, but I'm hoping to find a function that actually generates the p value AND the tvalue?

Answer (score 3):

Paul, I did exactly this for a psychological testing system (www.coolidgetests.com) and found it really wasn't that difficult to do on my own.  Like you, I searched and searched for an available solution.  It was intimidating at first to admit defeat and start writing code, but in the end I found it's wasn't too bad.

In my case, the user takes a test that generates a result (1-4)  All get jammed into a DB.  To do the report, I select the entire group of answers for the selected test, split them out for the answers that are scored normally and those that are reversed (1=4, 2=3, etc) then change those over with a switch statement.  The two arrays are combined, then calculation functions go through to generate T, Z, and other relevant statistical scores.  I kick out charts very simply via a table that's shaded based on calculated percentage.

UPDATE -

Here's my Z and T-Score Functions:

```
function calculateZscore($scale, $median, $stdiv) {
        if ($stdiv != 0) {
            $zval = ($scale - $median) / $stdiv;
        }

        else $zval = 0;
        return $zval;
    }

    function calculateTscore($zval) {
        $tval = 50+ (10) * ($zval);
        return $tval;
    }
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have the functions that generate the T score, adn then the subsequent p value?

Comment: Updated with my Z- and T-score functions.  I've broken each out because they're in use elsewhere on the reporting app.  Essentially, $scale is the summed answers, median and STDIV (standard deviation) are known numbers that were provided to me and are drawn from the DB for each scale.